# How to set alarm on specific day in calendar

Tags: android, calendar

I need to set alarm in my app to specific day that has been choosen from calendar ? As I have noticed Alarm doesn't have such method. I understnad that I can do this usign calendar and setting the time amount left for this date. But for example if user changes date,what happens ? 
Maybe this question is stupid,sorry, I am newbie.

Comment: Check this out: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html

And try writing some code, when you get there come back and ask a more specific question.

Answer (score 0):

By using the AlarmManager class, you should be able to do this:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

Use `public void set (int type, long triggerAtTime, PendingIntent operation)` to set the time to fire it.

Use `void setRepeating(int type, long triggerAtTime, long interval, PendingIntent operation)` to schedule a repeating alarm.

Here's how you can do this with your specified (date, hoursOfDay, minute, seconds and even millis):

```
   AlarmManager mAlarmManager = (AlarmMAnager)  Context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
   Calendar mCal = Calendar.getInstance();
   Calendar mCalSet = (Calendar) mCal.clone();

   mCalSet.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
   mCalSet.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
   mCalSet.set(Calendar.SECOND, second);
   mCalSet.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, millis);

   if(calSet.compareTo(calNow) <= 0){
    //Today Set time passed, count to tomorrow
    mCalSet.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
   }

   mAlarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, mCalSet.getTimeInMillis(), yourOperation);
```